# Can Mirth be configured so a channel will only run during weekdays?

Tags: mirth

Using Mirth 3.1.0.x, can Mirth be configured so a channel will only run during weekdays?

[image]

Comment: You may create one more field in your database and configure a trigger to fill this field only weekdays. Then pull the data in Mirth as usual checking for this field's value.

Comment: I wish Mirth channels would support chron expressions for polling interval.

Comment: There is one if you turn your channel's Source Connector to JavaScript Reader. Then you can configure Polling Settings to fire once a day (or even once a week in milliseconds), and use Source connector filter to verify if it's a weekday and poll data from the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Polling for a channel can only be set to an internal or specific time (hh:mm).
but you can control the output to occur only during week days.

Edit Channel, select a Destination, right-click and select Edit Transformer

[image]

Wrap functional code in the following:

```
var d=new Date();
var weekday=new Array(7);
weekday[0]="Sunday";
weekday[1]="Monday";
weekday[2]="Tuesday";
weekday[3]="Wednesday";
weekday[4]="Thursday";
weekday[5]="Friday";
weekday[6]="Saturday";

if ( weekday[d.getDay()]=='Saturday' || weekday[d.getDay()]=='Sunday')
{

}
else 
{
   <your code>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Mirth channels can be scheduled using java script.

Refer below post, this will help you to schedule mirth channel.

[Channel Scheduling with Javascript.](http://www.mirthcorp.com/community/forums/showthread.php?t=3498)

Just follow below step,

1) Create one channel, set source connector type as JavaScript Reader

2) Paste below Code in JavaScript.

```
importPackage(Packages.com.mirth.connect.server.userutil);logger.info("STARTING");

/* ADD Logic for time checks */
if(Your Time condition for Stop channel)
{
    ChannelUtil.stopChannel("YourChannelName"); 
    logger.info("STOPPING Channel");
}
if(Your Time condition for Start channel)
{   
    ChannelUtil.startChannel("YourChannelName");
    logger.info("STARTING Channel");
}
return "<MESSAGE>xxxxxxxx</MESSAGE>";
```

- Replace your channel name which you want to schedule in place of
  "YourChannelName"
- Place condition in IF for start and stop channel.

Comment: I wish I liked Javascript more than I do.

Comment: Please review my edited answer which help you easily to understand.